# Where does the data's are stored when using Backbone.localstorage()?

Tags: backbone.js

im doing a sample todo application by using a tutorial .. In that they are using  Backbone.localstorage , my doubt is Where does the data's will be stored when using Backbone.localstorage()?

Answer (score 1):

localstorage will save all of your todos data within your browser, instead of sending them to a server.

---

-So that when you use  Backbone.localstorage() the data is with you in your browser than to store it on server side and will get accessed from browser only

-You may refer the link  http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: thanks and yes i know its in browser .. but in browser where it is stored?? like cookies or cache or sessions?? where it is stored?

Comment: It will get stored as a cache data.

Comment: can i see any references for your answer??

Comment: may be you can refer this
http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/08/fast-caching-in-backbone-js-using-localstorage/

Comment: your answer is wrong.. coz it stores in cookies.. not in cache.. i ran the application,add the data, then clear one by one.. the datas are not avail only when clearing cookies..not cache...

Comment: I will test at my side and will check about it.

Comment: I tried it and after deleting the cache and cookie.
May be it was the cookie but still am not that much satisfied. cause I think the data should be cache memory. May be I have to read more about that.

Comment: But for what purpose you are storing data and which data?

Comment: Take a look at this link may be you will get the clear idea. 
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

[image: Do you want this?]

I'm taking this on http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/

Want to know what is localstorage indeed?

See it in your computer:

`C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`

You will find
`http_todomvc.com_0.localstorage`

If you try to edit the file with your notepad, you will find it's a `sqlite3` datebase indeed.

Comment: Thank you very much Liber.. people thinks that this is not a useful question..but u got it correct.. thank u...